# Repeating Again - LLALCK+MyriadPro-SemiboldIt: FT_Select_Charmap failed: error 6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

I had asked this question couple of days before, but unfortunately didn't get any solution and replies.

Hoping to get one this time.

I have a pdf file that I download from server and display it in web view.

Whenever pdf file is displayed, following error is displayed on console:

LLALCK+MyriadPro-SemiboldIt: FT_Select_Charmap failed: error 6 
I read somewhere that the font type is missing. But I am still not sure what the error is exactly about. Error occurs in both simulator and iPhone.

```
I tried installing font as well on Mac, but it still has same error.
```

I am displaying pdf in webview in following manner:

```
 NSString *path = [prefs objectForKey:@"filePath"];

 NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];

 [webView loadRequest:request];
```

Please help in how to avoid this error!

Comment: That sounds like the PDF is broken - can you post a sample somewhere so we can take a look at it? Hard to suggest a solution without knowing exactly what is wrong. And have you tried viewing the PDF in other (desktop) viewers? Preview on Mac? Adobe Reader or Acrobat?

Comment: unfortunately, i can't post my pdf file on the forum as its meant for client only. But I have tried it opening on Mac and it works fine. Even it opens up properly on simulator as well as phone, but at the same time above error is displayed on console.

Comment: Without a sample PDF all we can do is guess. If you cannot post the whole file, at least post all the PDF objects related to font display. If you don't know which they are, you definitively have to post the PDF for being helped.

Comment: I am opening pdf in uiwebview, how can i find out objects related to font display?

Comment: Please help...stuck from many days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to prevent the error by embedding the font in the PDF

Comment: I think it depends on what tools you use to create the pdf, it seems possible in Adobe acrobat: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/605334

Comment: I am opening pdf in uiwebview. I am not using any viewer like Acrobat in the app. How do I still embedd fonts?

Comment: Excuse me for not explaining it properly. It seems to me that the application rendering the pdf has no access to the font requested. When you save the PDF, there might be an option to 'embed fonts'. This should "attach" the font to the PDF, this might fix the issue you're having.

Comment: Ok, got it. Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Any ideas on how to do it??